# Error in importing google contacts

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, contacts, import-contacts

I am using this to get all gmail contacts from my id something@xyz.com:

[Import Gmail or Google contacts using Google Contacts Data API and OAuth 2.0 in PHP](http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/)

However, I get only 30-40/300 contacts displayed. And when I set the max_results to very high value, i get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as     
XML' in C:\xampp\htdocs\oauth\oauth.php:80 Stack trace: #0   
C:\xampp\htdocs\oauth\oauth.php(80): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown  
in C:\xampp\htdocs\oauth\oauth.php on line 80
```

Answer (score 0):

The maximum amount you can get for a `feed` is 100. If you go above this then bad things happen. You can use `startIndex` in combination with the `max-results` to specify where you want to get from and how many at a time.

```
 # max-results - max is 100 entries
 # startIndex - Used for paging so you can get the next bunch of results
```

Check [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) for more information on the layout of the XML, information on what some of the other method you can use are, and language specific methods. Try looking at the **Retrieving contacts using query parameters** and **Retrieving all contacts** sections for what you need here.